# Which function should I look into to make a socket in C?

Tags: c, linux, sockets

What function should I look into to create a socket for my mini-ftp server in C in the stdlib, except `recv`, `send` and all system calls that make a socket non-blocking?

Comment: there's no socket in C just like there isn't a screen or a mouse. There are only files and character streams. You need to use system-specific sockets

Comment: start with `man socket`, and then follow man pages for referred commands for examples.

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of guides for this sort of thing, in particular see [Beej's Guide to Network Programming](https://beej.us/guide/bgnet/html/) for working with Linux. There are similar / equivelant APIs exposed in Windows and other operating systems.

Fundamentally though, if you're using Liunx, you'll be interested in:

- [`socket()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/socket.2.html) to create the socket
- [`connect()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/connect.2.html) / [`bind()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/bind.2.html) and [`listen()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/listen.2.html) to connect or listen
- [`send()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/send.2.html) and [`recv()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/recv.2.html) to send and receive

If you're interested in non-blocking I/O, then the "*[Blocking](https://beej.us/guide/bgnet/html/#blocking)*" section will help.

Comment: the OP didn't specify that this would run on Linux

Comment: Very true... I've added wording for that.

Comment: Sorry, yes it is Linux, and i can't use send / recv at all

Comment: What do you mean by "_can't use `send()` / `recv()`_"?

Comment: i'am not authorized tho

Comment: Could you give more information on this? I suspect you'll have a difficult time without... at the minimum you'll need to use the underlying syscalls... or you'll have to write your own user-space networking stack, which will require much more effort, and a much higher level of permission on the system(!)

Comment: You can use read and write on TCP sockets. There are `sendto()` and `recvfrom()` too.  In fact, there’s a superabundance of calls that can be used to communicate over sockets.

Comment: "_You can use read and write on TCP sockets._" - you can, but isn't this generally considered a bad idea? I forget why... aside from the missing `flags` arg.

Comment: "_There are `sendto()` and `recvfrom()` too_" - indeed, but aren't these the equivelant to `send()` / `recv()` on TCP sockets, possibly even sharing underlying syscall(s)?